# ActionBarSherlock Spinner not updating

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have modified the example ActionBarSherlock/samples/demos/ListNavigation/
See my github fork [here](https://github.com/ccoffey/ActionBarSherlock) for the changes.

In summary

I have added

1. MyArrayAdapter
2. my_spinner_dropdown_item.xml

I have modified ListNavigation.java

```
1. -25 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = new CustomArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, mLocations);
2. +25 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = new MyArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, mLocations);
```

The issue is as follows.

When running on an AVD with Android 4.0, I get the expected and desired result.
Each time the Spinner dropdown is opened the numbers beside each item increment.

[image]

When running on an AVD with Android 2.2, I do NOT get the expected and desired result.
The Spinner dropdown only updates the first two times it is opened, then it never updates again.

Whats really weird is setText() is still being called and count is still incremented but the new values are just never being drawn.

[image]

Motivation for fixing this issue? Google's gmail app has a similar feature, dynamic counts inside a Spinner dropdown menu. This is actually where I got my feature idea from.

[image]